# PHP script not running when I submit form

Tags: php, html, forms

This is my HTML form:

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel heading">
                    <h1 style="text-align: center;">Choose your difficulty level </h1>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <fieldset>
                            <form action="backup.php" method="POST">
                                <h4>What is your difficulty level?</h4>
                                <select name="startdiff" class="form-control">
                                    <option value="5">5</option>
                                    <option value="10">10</option>
                                    <option value="15">15</option>
                                </select>
                                <br />
                                <input type="button" name="subdiff" class="btn-primary btn-lg btn-success" value="Let's go!">
                            </form>
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And this is what "backup.php" looks like:

```
<?php
include('connect.php');
include('my_class.php');

$admin = new User();

if (isset($_POST['subdiff']))
{

    $difficulty = $_POST['startdiff'];

    $admin->set_difficulty($difficulty);

    header('Location: getstarted.php');

}


?>
```

Note that I named it `backup.php` because my POST methods were all contained in one huge switch method but this specific form is the only one giving me problems, so please don't advise me on conventional naming methods.

What could be the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by *not running*? It's not setting the difficulty? Or redirecting? Or never gets to `backup.php`?

Comment: What's in the PHP error log?

Comment: Is the backup.php file in the same directory as the HTML?

Comment: Have you tried to change `<input type="button">` to `<input type="submit">`?

Comment: @BenM It actually doesn't do anything at all when I click the <input> button, and it doesn't redirect to "getstarted.php"

Comment: Read the duplicate, @rickdenhaan is right.

Comment: @rickdenhaan You're a f****** savior. I can't believe I missed that. You just rescued me from 2 more hours of frustration. 

Yes, I'm new to this.